# Differentiation inside integration

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

How to deal with the differentiation inside integration like this?

$$ I = \int d\theta_1 d\theta_2 \frac{df(\theta_1 , \theta_2)}{d\theta_1 d\theta_2} cos\theta_1$$

I want to evaluate this integral using any language like python. The primary reason I'm confused is how I will think the differentiation part inside the integral.

Do you think we can cancel the integration over $d \theta_1$ with $\frac{d}{d\theta_1}$ or $d \theta_2$ with $\frac{d}{d\theta_2}$?

I was confused is because we have to take the integral over both $d \theta_ 1$ and $d\theta_2$

Reference equation which I was following:  equation no (39) http://wwwcompass.cern.ch/compass/notes_public/2010-2.pdf

Comment: Do you mean to use $$\frac{df(\theta_1,\theta_2)}{d\theta_1d\theta_2}$$
to represent $$\frac{\partial ^2f(\theta_1,\theta_2)}{\partial \theta_1\partial\theta_2}.$$

Comment: Dear Melody, I was also confused initially. I was following equation (39) of this http://wwwcompass.cern.ch/compass/notes_public/2010-2.pdf  . What do you think?